# How do I make GVim use the icon in my icon theme?

Tags: themes, icons, vim, gvim

Instead of my pretty Faenza icon, it's using a rather ugly one.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Faenza icon theme? Icons for `vim` were added in Faenza 0.8

Comment: I am. The problem was the absolute path in the gvim.desktop file :)

Comment: This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/740842) that's now reported fixed. Probably to release in oneiric.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a known issue.
The workaround is mentioned in the gnome-look.org [Faenza](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Faenza?content=128143) page:

> - Some applications are configured to always use the same icon regardless of the selected theme: e.g. **vim**,  emacs23, gcolor2, bluefish, hardinfo, defcon, gufw, pithos, goldendict, rssowl, picasa, netbeans, gazpacho.
> - To display the Faenza icon, edit as root the `/usr/share/applications/application_name.desktop` file and locate the line beginning with 'Icon='. Replace the fullpath icon name by the one of the Faenza icon (usually, it's the name of the application itself) without the extension.
> - Don't forget to make a backup before changing one of those files.
> - In some cases, you need to reinitialize the item in Gnome menu editor to display the new icon.
> - Vim desktop file is `/usr/share/applications/gvim.desktop`

Comment: Clarification: "fullpath icon name by the one of the Faenza icon." So Faenza's vim.svg means you should use `Icon=vim` (don't include the extension). That way it will work for other icon themes that provide an icon for vim.